# How can I print all executed subroutines?

Tags: perl, trace, call-graph

E.g. I have following Perl script

```
{ 
    package A;

    {
        package B;

        sub _y {
            print "Just Another Perl Hacker\n";

        }

    }

    sub _x {
        print "Hello world!\n";
        B::_y();
    }
}


use strict;
use warnings;

_x();
```

How can I print every executed sub with package qualifier to STDERR or any log file?

E.g. from the script above I expect to see the following output:

```
1 A::_x()
2 B::_y()
```

I presume that it's possible to do with debugger like Devel::NYTProf, but I haven't found particular debugger modules or their params for that simple task.

Any ideas?

Comment: This code won't work. The last line should be `A::_x()` instead of just `_x()`

Comment: Hmm, code is working at my side, no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with the standard perl debugger:

```
$ PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop frame=1" perl -d prog.pl
  entering CODE(0x260cd78)
   entering strict::import
  entering CODE(0x260cd18)
   entering warnings::import
Package try.pl.
  entering DB::Obj::_init
  entering A::_x
Hello world!
   entering B::_y
Just Another Perl Hacker
```

(Note that I had to change `_x();` to `A::_x();` to get your code to run.)

If you want to place the output in a file, add `LineInfo=filenamehere`. See [`perldoc perldebug`](https://perldoc.pl/perldebug) for details. (In particular, if you change the options to say `frame=2`, you also get messages for returning from subroutines.)

The `CODE` references are for the implicit `BEGIN` blocks around `use` statements:

```
use strict;
```

really means

```
BEGIN {
    require "strict.pm";
    strict->import();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thinking about debugging modules puts you on the right track. When debug mode is enabled, Perl calls the function `DB::DB()` at every execution step in your program. From here you can extract the subroutine name from the `caller` builtin (which will include the package name), and output it as you see fit.

Start with a file called `Devel/AllSubs.pm` somewhere in your `@INC` path:

```
package Devel::AllSubs;
my $count = 0;
my $last_sub = '::';
sub DB::DB {
    my ($pkg, $file, $line,$sub) = caller(1);
    if ($sub ne $last_sub) {
        print STDERR ++$count," $sub\n";
        $last_sub = $sub;
    }
}
1;
```

And then run your program as

```
$ perl -d:AllSubs script.pl
```

Sample output:

```
1 A::_x
Hello world!
2 B::_y
Just Another Perl Hacker
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but your code has syntax error near ")["

Comment: @PaulSerikov, Fixed

Comment: Note that this will greatly slow down the program.

Comment: This will print the subs multiple times each, even multiple times per call. Adding  `|| !$seen{$_}++` to the `if` will do it.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution, using the already-mentioned [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) (a profiler instead of a debugger, to be more precise), which doesn't require you to write any additional code and gives you a lot more information.

```
% perl -d:NYTProf yourscript.pl
```

This will by default create an `nytprof.out` file. You can then do:

```
% nytprofcalls nytprof.out
```

which will give you detailed call information. An example script:

```
use strict;

sub f1 {
  print "hi;\n";
  f2();
}

sub f2 {
  print "hi2\n";
}

f1();
```

and sample output:

```
main::f1;main::f2 30
main::f1;main::CORE:print 124
main::f1;main::f2;main::CORE:print 40
main::BEGIN@1 4262
main::f1 113
main::BEGIN@1;strict::import 39
main::BEGIN@1;strict::BEGIN@7 396
main::BEGIN@1;strict::BEGIN@7;strict::CORE:match 58
```

You can see that NYTProf also lists calls to core function (CORE::print), among other things.

As a bonus, you can see the whole profile output using:

```
% nytprofhtml
```

then open the report page, e.g. using:

```
% firefox nytprof/index.html
```

You can see the subroutines that were executed (ordered by how long they run), how many times they were run, and much much more.

Comment: Yes, NYTProf is great tool, but for profiling, not for code tracing. NYTProf shows listing of executed functions in order by time wasted, not chance to sort by original order. By the way, you can disable logging core function calls by setting `start=init` instead of default `start=begin`. I created a playground repository for testing tracer modules from cpan, you are welcome to check and contribute https://github.com/pavelsr/perl-debug-example